# changing the font of the xthicklabels from a stylesheet in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want to use a non-standard font for labels on the axes of my matplotlib graph. I cannot assume users have installed the font, so I am providing the ttf file.

I have it working by doing the following:

```
fname = '/bla/bla/myfont.ttf'    
ticks_font = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname = fontPath, style='normal', size=12, weight='normal', stretch='normal')
for label in ax.get_xticklabels() :
    label.set_fontproperties(ticks_font)
```

However, as I have many graphs with different styles, I want to move all layout to stylesheets. I've tried to do:

```
 font.serif : '/bla/bla/myfont.ttf'
 font.family :'serif'
```

But that doesn't seem to work.